# How to use SQL Workbench J / Redshift to read local csv or txt file?

Tags: sql, load

I want to read local csv or txt files using sql workbench J / Redshift, store as a temporary table but not passing to Amazon S3.

I tried the following:

```
    WbImport -file=c:/work/test_1.txt
             -table=test_1
             -filecolumns=user_id,pay_date,test_1
             -dateformat="yyyy-MM-dd";
```

However, it tells me target table does not exist.
How to fix it please?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First, create a temp table with the headers in your *.csv/*.txt file.

```sql
create temp table test_1  (colA varchar(256), colb date, colc int);
```

you need to explicitly mention the column type and name as the csv/txt file.

the `-table=test_1` <- points to the temp table name you created.